# 3NF Database Normalization

Tags: sql, database, database-design, data-modeling, normalization

There is a report table for overdue DVD rentals. The store has multiple copies of the same DVD (they are all numbered to be identified). How can I normalize this data to meet 3NF requirements?

[Normalization http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7804/normalization.jpg](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/7804/normalization.jpg)

Comment: Please tag as [homework] if that is the case.

Comment: This is a bit like a homework question: Are you expecting us to do your work for you?  Perhaps if you showed what you've done so far, and what you're stuck on, people would be more willing to help.

Comment: Theres no question that this is a homework question, given the sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at objects--actors:

```
1. Customer
2. Title
3. Physical Medium (DVD, the thing you take home when borrowing)
4. Artist
5. Rental (act of renting = transaction)
```

- One **artist** can author many **titles** (moves, albums); a **title** (album) can be performed by several **artists**.
- One **title** can have many physical-**media** (dvd, tape, blue ray) copies; a **medium** has one **title** only.
- One **medium** (DVD) can be rented by many **customers** (one at the time); a **customer** can **rent** many **media** (DVD). `Media.Status` tracks availability of a medium (DVD).

[image: rental_model_01]

Answer (score 10):

The data model:

### `VIDEO_ARTIST` table

- `ARTIST_ID`, pk
- `FIRST_NAME`
- `LAST_NAME`

### `VIDEOS` table

- `VIDEO_ID`, pk
- `VIDEO_TITLE`
- `ARTIST_ID`, fk
- `RUNNING_TIME`

### `VIDEO_COPIES` table

- `VIDEO_COPY_ID`, pk
- `VIDEO_ID`, fk
- `VIDEO_COPY_NUMBER`

Notice that I'm not using the primary key for the value displayed to the users.

1. Copy numbers could change, but you don't want to break referencial integrity
2. Do not expose table keys

### `VIDEO_RENTALS` table

- `VIDEO_COPY_ID`, pk, fk
- `ACCOUNT_ID`, pk, fk
- `DUE_DATE`, pk

### `VIDEO_RENTALS_ACCOUNTS` table

- `ACCOUNT_ID`, pk
- `ACCOUNT_NUMBER`, unique
- `FIRST_NAME`
- `LAST_NAME`

Same logic regarding the `ACCOUNT_NUMBER` as with the `VIDEO_COPY_NUMBER`...

Here's the SQL to use based on the data model to get the report example you provided:

```
SELECT v.video_title 'Video Title',
       aa.artist_name 'Artist',
       vc.video_copy_number 'Copy Number',
       v.running_time 'Length',
       vr.due_date 'Date Due',
       acct.borrower_name 'Borrower',
       acct.account_number 'Card Number'
  FROM VIDEO_RENTALS vr
  JOIN VIDEO_COPIES vc ON vc.video_copy_id = t.video_copy_id
  JOIN VIDEOS v ON v.video_id = vr.video_id
  JOIN (SELECT a.artist_id,
               a.firstname +' '+ a.lastname AS artist_name
          FROM ARTIST a) aa ON aa.artist_id = vr.artist_id
  JOIN (SELECT vra.account_id,
               vra.account_number,
               vra.firstname +' '+ vra.lastname AS borrower_name
          FROM VIDEO_RENTALS_ACCOUNTS vra) acct ON acct.account_id = vr.account_id
```